# Python: How do you convert n-bits to base 64?

Tags: python, binary, base64

I have this: `struct.pack('I', 0b10101010101100101010001000001000).encode('base64')`
which is good for converting 32 bits to base 64... but is there an easy way to convert any number of bits to base 64?

like, anywhere between 128 and 512?

EDIT: 
where I'm at:
My original command:

```
>>> struct.pack('I', 0b10101010101100101010001000001000).encode('base64')  
'CKKyqg==\n'
```

One of the suggestions is to use \x for hex and convert that... so far so good.

```
>>> struct.pack('I', 0b10101010101100101010001000001000).encode('hex')
'08a2b2aa'
>>> '\x08\xa2\xb2\xaa'.encode('base64')
'CKKyqg==\n'
```

but can I do the samething with binary?

```
>>> '\b10101010\b10110010\b10100010\b00001000'.encode('base64')
'CDEwMTAxMDEwCDEwMTEwMDEwCDEwMTAwMDEwCDAwMDAxMDAw\n'
nope =(
```

Comment: Why are you using binary literals?

Comment: For saving / reading input to a neural network.

Comment: So it's user input? Are you planning to run eval on it?

Comment: it's not user input, it's completely automated. =\

Comment: You're still trying to use Python literals for something that doesn't appear to be hardcoded. That's not going to help when you get real data. What format is your actual data coming to you in? A string of "0" and "1" characters?

Comment: an array of 0 and 1s -_-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an arbitrary-long binary string, use string hex escapes:

```
'\x00\x01\x02\x03'.encode('base64')
```

So your example would be:

```
'\xaa\xb2\xa2\x08'.encode('base64')
```

Comment: looks like it's just encoding the ascii value of each of those characters.... so, the base64 version ends up being longer... I'm trying to more compactly represent my data.

Comment: You're misunderstanding what's actually happening. It's not encoding the ascii values, it's making a 4 byte string with the exact value you specified. You shouldn't be working with actual bits either, what are you trying to do?

Comment: guess not... both what I have, and your hex version of what I have encode to the same thing. thanks!

Comment: wait, how do I do that with binary though? using \b doesn't work =\

Comment: you don't (and shouldn't) do that with binary. What are you trying to do?

Comment: reading output from, and sending input to a neural network, all of the data needs to be a bit per neuron, and when we save training files, we want to store them in base 64, because it is compact, but need to convert it to binary to train the network.

Comment: Why not store your data as binary to begin with?

Comment: we are eventually going to do that, we decided we don't need to read anything. so we're just going to define our own file format... yay!

Answer (score 1):

I have written an [article](http://www.artificial-informagic.com/2011/05/01/convert-block-digits-base-x-base-y) which describes a simple solution in Python which can be used to transfrom a series of numbers from and to arbitrary number bases. Using the proposed solution you could transform a list of binary digits into any encoding representation you like. Note however, that the result of a conversion will not contain padding characters as it just doesn't need them. Maybe it serves your needs, maybe not ;)